# SAP OpenUI5 - SearchField break List template if a search string doesn't provides data

Tags: javascript, filter, sapui5

I'm developing a web application using SAP OpenUI5 framework.

I have an issue filtering data in a List table, with SearchField widget.
The SearchField is defined in xml view:

```
<SearchField id="taskSearchBox" enableClear="true" liveChange="onSearchTasks"></SearchField>
```

on my controller I've defined function called at every change in the SearchField:

```
        onSearchTasks : function (oEvent) {

            var self = this;

            let searchField = 'Title';
            let searchString = oEvent.getSource().getValue() ;              

            let oFilter = new Filter(searchField, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchString);

            self.getView().byId('tableTask').getBinding('items').filter([oFilter]);

        },
```

Here's a GIF of my issue:

[image]

Comment: self.getView().byId('tableTask').getBinding('items').filter([oFilter], false);

Comment: @santhosh tried to add `false` to `filter` but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the creation of the binding, between model and Table items.

Code with issue:

```
                let oTable = self.getView().byId('tableTask');
                oTable.bindAggregation('items', {
                    path:'/rowsData',   // field name of JSON object containing rowsData
                    template: oColumnsListItem,  // rowTemplate of cells
                });
```

Code without issue:

```
                let oTable = self.getView().byId('tableTask');
                oTable.removeAllItems();                                        
                oTable.removeAllAggregation();
                oTable.bindAggregation('items', {
                    path:'/rowsData',   // field name of JSON object containing rowsData
                    template: oColumnsListItem,  // rowTemplate of cells
                });
```

so adding these two lines of code:

```
                oTable.removeAllItems();                                        
                oTable.removeAllAggregation();
```

solved the issue.

Honestly do not know if it's the correct way or just a workaround, but now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    onSearchTasks : function (oEvent) {

        var self = this;
        let oFilter = "";
        let searchField = 'Title';
        let searchString = oEvent.getSource().getValue() ;              
     if(searchString) {
         oFilter = new Filter(searchField,sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchString);
       }    
      self.getView().byId('tableTask').getBinding('items').filter([oFilter]);
      }
```

Comment: Hi, if there is no value in searchString variable then don't make a filter object (oFilter), just filter the table binding items with blank array .

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Tried your code but unfortunately it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The control you're using is deprecated.  You need to use [sap.m.SearchField](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SearchField/overview).  I believe the error is because of the enableClear property of the deprecated field.

Comment: I was using the sap.m.SearchField, default namespace for my XML is xmlns="sap.m"
You are right I was wrongly using the "enableClear" attribute, in fact it doesn't affect anything. I have deleted it in my code. Thanks.